# onedrive does not return refresh token even with 'offline_access' scope

Tags: node.js, api, onedrive

I'm trying to get the tokens of user's to integrate one drive in an APP that's I'm building

I first get the auth URL, here's the endpoint implementation

```
const pca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(config);
exports.getAuthUrl = (req, res) => {
  const authCodeUrlParameters = {
    scopes: ['user.read', 'files.readwrite', 'offline_access'],

    redirectUri: 'https://localhost:8080/onedrive',
  };
  // get url to sign user in and consent to scopes needed for application
  pca
    .getAuthCodeUrl(authCodeUrlParameters)
    .then((response) => {
      res.status(200).send(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)));
};
```

Then using the code that I got back after the client auth is successful is passed as a parameter in a second endpoint to obtain the tokens

```
exports.getToken = (req, res) => {
  const tokenRequest = {
    code: req.query.code,
    scopes: ['user.read', 'files.readwrite', 'offline_access'],

    redirectUri: 'https://localhost:8080/onedrive',
  };

  pca
    .acquireTokenByCode(tokenRequest)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('\nResponse: \n:', response);
      res.status(200).send(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).send(error);
    });
};
```

So as mentioned in the official doc if you add the offline_access scope you get back a refresh token
[image: official doc]

does anyone have any experience with this ? I used these two libraries that part of the code is already provided by Microsoft `const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a few days of research I found out that msal-node does not expose the refresh token to the end-user by design. It is stored and used internally under the hood when you need a new access token. You should call acquireTokenSilent each time you need an access token and msal-node will manage the tokens by either returning a cached token to you or using the refresh token to acquire a new access token.
So what I did is actually make the call directly to the endpoint provided by Microsoft
You should first get the code using the URL provided in this doc `[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/msa-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online][1]`
the take the code and pass it in the next enpoint which is the following

```
exports.getToken = async (req, res) => {
  request.post(
    'https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf',
    {
      form: {
        code: req.body.code,
        client_id: 'CLIENT-ID',
        redirect_uri: 'REDIRECT-URI',
        client_secret: 'CLIENT-SECRET',
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      },
    },
    async function (err, httpResponse, body) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ Message: err.message });
      } else {
        let response = JSON.parse(body);
       res.status(200).send({ Body: JSON.parse(body) });
      }
    }
  );
};
```

and that's how I made it work, using msal there was no way

Comment: I read msal-node docs, their bing ads api docs and couldn't find a solution for it, but here you are saving us with this answer! Thank you!!

Comment: there is a way to do it. after calling 'acquireTokenByCode' ,  'pca' now  has the refresh token. 
const tokenCache = pca.getTokenCache().serialize();
            const refreshTokenObject = (JSON.parse(tokenCache)).RefreshToken
            const refreshToken = refreshTokenObject[Object.keys(refreshTokenObject)[0]].secret;

Check my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Here is How to get the Refresh and Access token..

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 * Licensed under the MIT License.
 */
const express = require("express");
const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');

const SERVER_PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:3000/redirect";

// Before running the sample, you will need to replace the values in the config, 
// including the clientSecret
const config = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/84fb56d3-e15d-4ae1-acd7-cbf83c4c0af3",
        clientSecret: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback(loglevel, message, containsPii) {
                console.log(message);
            },
            piiLoggingEnabled: false,
            logLevel: msal.LogLevel.Verbose,
        }
    }
};

// Create msal application object
const pca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(config);

// Create Express App and Routes
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const authCodeUrlParameters = {
        scopes: ["user.read","offline_access"],
        redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI,
        prompt:'consent'
    };
    // get url to sign user in and consent to scopes needed for application
    pca.getAuthCodeUrl(authCodeUrlParameters).then((response) => {
        res.redirect(response);
    }).catch((error) => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)));
});

app.get('/redirect', (req, res) => {
    const tokenRequest = {
        code: req.query.code,
        scopes: ["user.read","offline_access"],
        redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI,
        accessType: 'offline',
    };
    pca.acquireTokenByCode(tokenRequest).then((response) => {
        const accessToken = response.accessToken;
        const refreshToken = () => {
            const tokenCache = pca.getTokenCache().serialize();
            const refreshTokenObject = (JSON.parse(tokenCache)).RefreshToken
            const refreshToken = refreshTokenObject[Object.keys(refreshTokenObject)[0]].secret;
            return refreshToken;
        }
        const tokens = {
            accessToken,
            refreshToken:refreshToken()
        }
        console.log(tokens)
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
    });
});


app.listen(SERVER_PORT, () => console.log(`Msal Node Auth Code Sample app listening on port ${SERVER_PORT}!`))
```

Comment: after calling 'acquireTokenByCode' , 'pca' now has the refresh token. const tokenCache = pca.getTokenCache().serialize(); const refreshTokenObject = (JSON.parse(tokenCache)).RefreshToken const refreshToken = refreshTokenObject[Object.keys(refreshTokenObject)[0]].secret;